# Grails: what are the other alternatives to sitemesh for gsp view layouts?

Tags: grails, template-engine, sitemesh

Sitemesh seems to be an open-source project with minimal activity and small user community. So, I was wondering whether there are (better) alternatives to sitemesh, as a templating layout engine ?
And if it is the case, how can one integrate it into a grails application?

Thank you,

Fabien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is interested in this question, you have sort of answers [here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Alternatives-to-sitemesh-for-gsp-view-layouts-tp1356070p1356070.html) 
Fabien.

Comment: Fabien, this link is no longer valid. Can you re-post it? thanks!